# How to retrieve a case-sensitive string from Oracle using flask-sqlalchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Is there any way to write a Sqlalchemy query (case sensitive) for oracle db which can differentiate between 'ABCdef' and 'abcd'). The current query is like this:

```
info = db.query(Table.name, Table.time_type,....)\
                .outerjoin( Table1.name == Table2.t2_name)\
                .......
```

Can any body suggest what I am missing in the query?

Cheers,
M

Answer (score 0):

I hear you saying that in the JOIN clause, you want 'ABCdef' != 'abcd', and also want 'ABCd' == 'abcd'.

The backend optimizer can't "see through" functions, such as `lower()`, which will prevent exploiting some indexes. Succinctly, "functions disable indexes".

Create a new derived column, use UPDATE to store case-smashed names in it, and index on it. Then do a simple equi-join.

EDIT: You revised your question to say A.name == B.tag_name is the equi-join of interest, where "equal" should have case-insensitive semantics. But the query optimizer "cannot see through" the lower() function - it would disable any index. We want to support high-speed joins using your custom equality test, and we'll use a little disk space to do it.

Alter table A to add a varchar column `name1`.

Similarly alter table B to add a `tag_name1` column.

These are derived columns that will be used just for the equi-join condition. Put case-smashed data in them: `update A set name1 = lower(name);`

Similarly for table B. You could truncate lengthy strings or otherwise munge the data to suit your app-specific notion of "equality".

Ensure that A has an index mentioning `name1`, and B has one for `tag_name1`.

Now your `ON` clause just asks for `name1 == tag_name1`.

Comment: Thanks(can you clarify more), actually in one table I have two rows like "ABCDef" and "abcdef" and hashes are stored in other table when I join both tables it combines the results. The resultant resultset combines all the hashes for both rows:

def tag_info(db, tag):
 rows.tag_info = db.query(A.name, A.time_type, A.object_type, A.synchronization, ....)\
    .outerjoin(B, A.name == B.tag_name)\
    .filter(A.name == tag)\
    .order_by(desc(B.since)).first()

Comment: "EDIT: You revised your question to say A.name == B.tag_name is the equi-join of interest, where "equal" should have case-insensitive semantics"
It should be case-sensitive not case insensitive